# "M.2 2280 PCIe TLC Opal" vs "M.2 2280 PCIe Gen4 Performance TLC Opal"

Tags: ssd

I'm configuring a [ThinkPad X1 Carbon](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpadx1/thinkpad-x1-carbon-gen-10-(14-inch-intel)/21cbcto1wwus2), and looking at the SSD. What is the difference between `M.2 2280 PCIe TLC Opal` and `M.2 2280 PCIe Gen4 Performance TLC Opal`? From what I've read [elsewhere](https://www.sportskeeda.com/gaming-tech/pcie-gen-4-vs-gen-3-do-need-spend-extra-ssds) Gen4 is faster+more expensive, but on the Lenovo page Gen4 is actually cheaper (screenshots below). What's going on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those SSD prices are insanely high. I would reccomend getting no SSD preinstalled and get your own SSD (you can get 2TB for under €250)

Comment: Unfortunately not an option to get it without the SSD but the prices seem on par with buying a compatible SSD from their [website](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/memory-and-storage/memory-and-storage-hard-drives/4xb0w79582) (~$500)

Comment: Don't buy the SSD from Lenovo then, if you search on amazon for 2TB SSD you will see the Lenovo prices are bad. And if it says NVMe it's compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a chat session with Lenovo to ask the difference between the two.  Basically the Gen4 Performance is the better SSD and it's cheaper at the moment because of their supply chain cost.